# Swift Firebase UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, refresh

I am trying to reload my tableview so users can get refreshed data related to their location. My current setup has it to where when I do a "pull to refresh" it will start adding duplicate data to the tableview instead of clearing it and replacing it with the new data. I feel like there is 1 line of code that will solve this problem but I don't know what it is, I feel like I've seen it before somewhere...

```
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    getTableViewData()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RegisteredLocationsTableView.handleRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    getTableViewData()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func getTableViewData() {
    databaseRef.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessName").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let key = snapshot.key

        if(key == self.loggedInUser?.uid) {
            print("Same as logged in user, so don't show!")
        } else {
            if let locationValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let lat = Double(locationValue["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(locationValue["businessLongitude"] as! String)
                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters : Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles : Double = ((distanceInMeters.description as String).doubleValue * 0.00062137)
                let distanceLabelText = "\(distanceInMiles.string(2)) miles away"

                var singleChildDictionary = locationValue
                singleChildDictionary["distanceLabelText"] = distanceLabelText as AnyObject
                singleChildDictionary["distanceInMiles"] = distanceInMiles as AnyObject
                self.usersArray.append(singleChildDictionary as NSDictionary)
                self.usersArray = self.usersArray.sorted {
                    !($0?["distanceInMiles"] as! Double > $1?["distanceInMiles"] as! Double)
                }
            }
            //insert the rows
            //self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.followUsersTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you populating the tableview using `userArray` ?

Comment: yes I am populating the tableview with userArray

Comment: In `handleRefresh` method try clearing the array data before calling `getTableViewData` using `self. userArray.removeAllObjects()`

Comment: I don't know if you can help out, but before I posted this question I was trying different things and ran "self.dataRef.removeValue()" and now my firebase data wont appear anymore

Comment: I don't understand what exact issue you are having. But according to the sample code you have posted, in method `getTableViewData` you are appending data in `userArray`. So, whenever you are calling `handleRefresh` new data is getting added in `userArray` with old data. First clear the previous data of `userArray` in `handleRefresh` then call method `getTableViewData`.

Comment: Figured it out, I accidentally deleted all my firebase data. LOL. Once I get populate it with data i'll try your solution

Comment: You gave the correct answer too bad I can't upvote your answer to give you credit :/

Comment: I will add my answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method `getTableViewData` try to do `usersArray.removeAll()`.

Also I would suggest not doing these inside `handleRefresh` method:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

Why: because you need to do it after you get the data using `getTableViewData()` method. And actually, you already do reload in the end of the `getTableViewData()` method. So just call also this there `refreshControl.endRefreshing()`. But you may ask that this refreshControl is not accessible from this method, that means you need to make it as a global property.

Let me know in comments if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exact issue you are having. But according to the sample code you have posted, in method `getTableViewData` you are appending data in `userArray`. So, whenever you are calling `handleRefresh` new data is getting added in `userArray` with old data. First clear the previous data of `userArray` in `handleRefresh` then call method `getTableViewData`.